# Using Fabric with no Authentication Methods

Tags: python, paramiko, fabric

When trying to connect via SSH, to a device that has no SSH authentication methods I keep getting the error that there are "No Authentication Methods Avaiable". But the thing is there there isnt any authentication mechanisms used. Does anyone know a good way to bypass the need for authentication and connect without using any of the typical methods? Right now I am trying to use Fabric (which uses Paramiko).

I have already tried doing things like providing blank password and username or just default login info for that server.

from fabric import Connection
c = Connection(host='192.168.1.1', user='root', port='22')
result = c.run('ls')

I hope to connect and use with the username root.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Here, you can try generating the ssh-id on local machine and copying it over to remote.

Run ssh-key gen on local node

```
ssh-keygen -t rsa -N "" -f ~/.ssh/id_rsa
```

Run ssh-copy id

```
ssh-copy-id -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub {remote_server_ip}
```